# Column Name has quotes

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a few column names that have spaces and double quotes in it.

For instance, currently the name of the column is:

Paints the "big picture" of what we aspire to accomplish

If I want to select it how do I do this since there's is double quotes in it?

For other columns I have been doing:

```
 SELECT 
  "Talks about future trends that will influence how our work gets done"
```

Which I can't do since I have "big picture" in the column name.

Comment: is it a column or a record? if you 
SELECT 
  "Talks about future trends that will influence how our work gets done" 

in sql server, it should display a record value, talks about future trends that will influence how our work gets done with no column name

Answer (score 1):

Snowflake appears to permit use of [double-quotes in identifiers](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/identifiers-syntax.html) if they are escaped when referenced:

```sql
SELECT "Paints the ""big picture"" of what we aspire to accomplish"
```

Answer (score 0):

With the caveat that this is only a workaround until you eliminate object names with double quotes -- for any object name wrapped in double quotes, you'll need to wrap them with three double quotes:

```
create or replace table """MY_TABLE""" ("""MESSAGE""" string);
insert into """MY_TABLE""" select 'Hello, world.';
select """MESSAGE""" from """MY_TABLE""";
```

The UI preview will not work with a table / column defined this way, and you may encounter other issues. Consider it a workaround until you can change the object names to eliminate double quotes.